# Iterparse object in Python is not returning iter object

Tags: python, xml

I'm working with the XML file in this [link](https://www.grants.gov/web/grants/xml-extract.html?p_p_id=xmlextract_WAR_grantsxmlextractportlet_INSTANCE_5NxW0PeTnSUa&p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_pos=1&p_p_col_count=2&download=GrantsDBExtract20180104v2.zip) (Downloadable file of 40MB). In this file, I'm expecting data from 2 types of tags.

Those are: `OpportunityForecastDetail_1_0` and `OpportunitySynopsisDetail_1_0`.

I wrote the following code for that:

```
ARTICLE_TAGS = ['OpportunitySynopsisDetail_1_0', 'OpportunityForecastDetail_1_0']

for _tag in ARTICLE_TAGS:
    f = open(xml_f)
    context = etree.iterparse(f, tag = _tag)

    for _, e in context:
        _id = e.xpath('.//OpportunityID/text()')
        text = e.xpath('.//OpportunityTitle/text()')
    f.close()
```

Then `etree.iterparse(f, tag = _tag)` is returning an object which is not iterable. I think this occurs when the tag is not found in the XML file.

So, I added name spaces to the iterable tag like this.

```
context = etree.iterparse(f, tag='{http://apply.grants.gov/system/OpportunityDetail-V1.0}'+_tag)
```

Now, it is creating an iterable object. But, I'm not getting any text. I tried other namespaces in that file. But, not working.

Please tell me the solution to this problem. This is a sample snippet of the XML file. `OpportunityForecastDetail_1_0` and `OpportunitySynopsisDetail_1_0` tags are repeated n number of times in the XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Grants xsi:schemaLocation="http://apply.grants.gov/system/OpportunityDetail-V1.0 https://apply07.grants.gov/apply/system/schemas/OppotunityDetail-V1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://apply.grants.gov/system/OpportunityDetail-V1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instace">
<OpportunitySynopsisDetail_1_0>
<OpportunityID>262148</OpportunityID>
<OpportunityTitle>Establishment of the Edmund S. Muskie Graduate Internship Program</OpportunityTitle>
</OpportunitySynopsisDetail_1_0>
<OpportunityForecastDetail_1_0>
<OpportunityID>284765</OpportunityID>
<OpportunityTitle>PPHF 2015: Immunization Grants-CDC Partnership: Strengthening Public Health Laboratories-financed in part by 2015 Prevention and Public Health Funds</OpportunityTitle>
</OpportunityForecastDetail_1_0>
</Grants>
```

Comment: Include a minimal but meaningful snippet of your 40 MB XML file in your question. A) Nobody downloads a file that large just to understand what your question is about. B) When the link goes away in the future, nobody can even download a file figure out what you question is about.

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you. Edited the question.

Comment: There are a number of problems here; you are not using the iterparse function correctly - see https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html for documentation, or http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm for more tutorials and links.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you are parsing XML that contains namespaces, you must use those namespaces when looking at tag names.
Second, `iterparse` doesn't take an argument named `tag`, so I don't see how your code could have worked as posted.
Finally, the elements returned from `iterparse` don't have a member function called `xpath`, so that can't have worked either.

Here is an example of how to parse XML using `iterparse`:

```
NS='{http://apply.grants.gov/system/OpportunityDetail-V1.0}'
ARTICLE_TAGS = [NS+'OpportunitySynopsisDetail_1_0', NS+'OpportunityForecastDetail_1_0']

with open(xml_f, 'r') as f:
    context = etree.iterparse(f)

    for _, e in context:
    if e.tag  in ARTICLE_TAGS:
        _id = e.find(NS+'OpportunityID')
        text = e.find(NS+'OpportunityTitle')
        print(_id.text, text.text)
```

As I said in my comment, the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is helpful, as is the [Effbot page on ElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm).  There are lots of other resources available; put `xml.etree.elementtree` into Google and start reading!